# How to randomly assign words in a Hangman game in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, random, jframe, css-position

So I am doing a Hang man game in Java for my Final Project in my Computer Science class. I have done the template for the Hang man (i.e. buttons and added the words needed). But I don't know how to draw the Hangman itself and how to randomly add the words (meaning so they will start guessing the words) to the program. What I am asking is how do I draw the Hangman if a letter was guessed wrong(or right, to write in the textfield). For the letters I have done JButtons because I think it would be easier, and added action listeners. I know the code is very long, but don't pay attention to the template, method Start is where I have my words and hints. Thank you in advance. Don't mind that I do not have a main method, I have a driver class that extends this class. (It was one of the requirements)

Solved!

```
    package hangman;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Hangman extends JFrame
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
    JButton a = new JButton("A"), b = new JButton("B"), c = new JButton("C"), d = new JButton("D"), ee = new JButton("E"), f = new JButton("F"), 
            g = new JButton("G"), h = new JButton("H"), i = new JButton("I"), j = new JButton("J"), k = new JButton("K"), l = new JButton("L"), 
            m = new JButton("M"), n = new JButton("N"), o = new JButton("O"), p = new JButton("P"), q = new JButton("Q"), r = new JButton("R"), 
            s = new JButton("S"), t = new JButton("T"), u = new JButton("U"), v = new JButton("V"), w = new JButton("W"), x = new JButton("X"), 
            y = new JButton("Y"), z = new JButton("Z");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    JButton hint = new JButton("Hint");
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome to Hang Man!  ");
    JLabel hintWord = new JLabel("Click the Button to show a hint!");
    Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.ITALIC, 24);
    JTextField theWord = new JTextField();
    Font font1 = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 34);

    public Hangman()
    {

        //Panel adding
        panel.add(restart);
        panel.add(theWord);
        panel.add(hint);
        panel.add(exit);
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(hintWord);
        panel.add(a);
        panel.add(b);
        panel.add(c);
        panel.add(d);
        panel.add(ee);
        panel.add(f);
        panel.add(g);
        panel.add(h);
        panel.add(j);
        panel.add(k);
        panel.add(l);
        panel.add(m);
        panel.add(n);
        panel.add(o);
        panel.add(p);
        panel.add(q);
        panel.add(r);
        panel.add(s);
        panel.add(t);
        panel.add(u);
        panel.add(v);
        panel.add(w);
        panel.add(x);
        panel.add(y);
        panel.add(z);
        add(panel);

        title.setFont(font);

         // JFrame properties 

         setSize(1024, 700);
         setTitle("Hangman");
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setVisible(true);

         this.setLayout(null);
         panel.setLayout(null);

         //Adding to the panel
         panel.add(restart);
         panel.add(theWord);
         panel.add(hint);
         panel.add(exit);
         panel.add(title);
         panel.add(hintWord);
         panel.add(a);
         panel.add(b);
         panel.add(c);
         panel.add(d);
         panel.add(ee);
         panel.add(f);
         panel.add(g);
         panel.add(h);
         panel.add(j);
         panel.add(k);
         panel.add(l);
         panel.add(m);
         panel.add(n);
         panel.add(o);
         panel.add(p);
         panel.add(q);
         panel.add(r);
         panel.add(s);
         panel.add(t);
         panel.add(u);
         panel.add(v);
         panel.add(w);
         panel.add(x);
         panel.add(y);
         panel.add(z);
         add(panel);

         // Positioning
         restart.setLocation(25,25);
         theWord.setLocation(100, 530);
         theWord.setEnabled(false);
         theWord.setSize(800, 100);
         theWord.setHorizontalAlignment(theWord.CENTER);
         theWord.setFont(font1);
         theWord.setForeground(Color.RED);
         hint.setLocation(600, 150);
         exit.setLocation(900, 25);
         title.setLocation(350, 25);
         a.setLocation(600, 250);
         b.setLocation(650, 250);
         c.setLocation(700, 250);
         d.setLocation(750, 250);
         ee.setLocation(800, 250);
         f.setLocation(850, 250);
         g.setLocation(900, 250);
         h.setLocation(950, 250);
         j.setLocation(600, 280);
         k.setLocation(650, 280);
         l.setLocation(700, 280);
         m.setLocation(750, 280);
         n.setLocation(800, 280);
         o.setLocation(850, 280);
         p.setLocation(900, 280);
         q.setLocation(950, 280);
         r.setLocation(600, 310);
         s.setLocation(650, 310);
         t.setLocation(700, 310);
         u.setLocation(750, 310);
         v.setLocation(800, 310);
         w.setLocation(850, 310);
         x.setLocation(900, 310);
         y.setLocation(950, 310);
         z.setLocation(750, 340);
         hintWord.setLocation(670, 150);

         // Action Listeners
        restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    restartActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        hint.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    hintActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    exitActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        a.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    aActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    bActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    cActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        d.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    dActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        ee.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    eeActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        f.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    fActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        g.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    gActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        h.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    hActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        j.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    jActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        k.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    kActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        l.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    lActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        m.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    mActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        n.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    nActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        o.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    oActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        p.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    pActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        q.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    qActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        r.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    rActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        s.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    sActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    tActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        u.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    uActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        v.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    vActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        w.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    wActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        x.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    xActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        y.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    yActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
        z.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    zActionPerformed(e);
                }
            });


    }
    public void Start()
    {
        String words[] = new String[26];
        String hints[] = new String[26];
        // Words along with hints
        words[0] = "president";
        hints[0] = "Leader.";
        words[1] = "exclamation";
        hints[1] = "Shout out.";
        words[2] = "statement";
        hints[2] = "To say.";
        words[3] = "television";
        hints[3] = "You watch it.";
        words[4] = "physics";
        hints[4] = "Form of Science.";
        words[5] = "algebra";
        hints[5] = "Form of math.";
        words[6] = "geometry";
        hints[5] = "Form of math.";
        words[7] = "difficult";
        hints[7] = "Hard.";
        words[8] = "extreme";
        hints[8] = "Intense.";
        words[9] = "procedure";
        hints[9] = "Steps.";
        words[10] = "ship";
        hints[10] = "Big Boat.";
        words[11] = "soldier";
        hints[11] = "Army.";
        words[12] = "lunch";
        hints[12] = "Meal.";
        words[13] = "hockey";
        hints[13] = "Sports.";
        words[14] = "tennis";
        hints[14] = "Sports.";
        words[15] = "soccer";
        hints[15] = "Sports.";
        words[16] = "football";
        hints[16] = "Sports.";
        words[17] = "basketball";
        hints[17] = "Sports.";
        words[18] = "bias";
        hints[18] = "One sided.";
        words[19] = "magazine";
        hints[19] = "Form of book.";
        words[20] = "computer";
        hints[20] = "Microsoft.";
        words[21] = "internet";
        hints[21] = "World Wide Web.";
        words[22] = "allegedly";
        hints[22] = "Supposedly.";
        words[23] = "system";
        hints[23] = "Network.";
        words[24] = "unison";
        hints[24] = "As one.";
        words[25] = "excited";
        hints[25] = "Upbeat.";

    }
    // Action Listeners
    public void restartActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        a.setEnabled(true);
        b.setEnabled(true);
        c.setEnabled(true);
        d.setEnabled(true);
        ee.setEnabled(true);
        f.setEnabled(true);
        g.setEnabled(true);
        h.setEnabled(true);
        j.setEnabled(true);
        k.setEnabled(true);
        l.setEnabled(true);
        m.setEnabled(true);
        n.setEnabled(true);
        o.setEnabled(true);
        p.setEnabled(true);
        q.setEnabled(true);
        r.setEnabled(true);
        s.setEnabled(true);
        t.setEnabled(true);
        u.setEnabled(true);
        v.setEnabled(true);
        w.setEnabled(true);
        x.setEnabled(true);
        y.setEnabled(true);
        z.setEnabled(true);
        hintWord.setText("Click the Button to show a hint!");
    }
    public void exitActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void hintActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        hintWord.setText("");
    }
    public void aActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        a.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void bActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void cActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        c.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void dActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        d.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void eeActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        ee.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void fActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        f.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void gActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        g.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void hActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        h.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void jActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        j.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void kActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        k.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void lActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        l.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void mActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        m.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void nActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        n.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void oActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        o.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void pActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        p.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void qActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        q.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void rActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        r.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void sActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        s.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void tActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        t.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void uActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        u.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void vActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void wActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        w.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void xActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        x.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void yActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        y.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public void zActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        z.setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Comment: I had a problem with that. I tried using different layout managers, but none of them seemed to help me organize my GUI, and it was my teacher's idea to actually use absolute location. Thank you for the insight! The problem that I am actually having is drawing the lines of the hangman (using absolute location as well [x1, y1, x2, y2])

Comment: *"it was my teacher's idea to actually use absolute location"*  Smack them upside the head and tell them to wake up to themselves.  If they sue you for taking that advice literally, don't involve me.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the lines you could use `drawline` in the `Graphics` class.

```
 g.drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
```

Docs:

> Draws a line, using the current color, between the points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Write down the coordinates to a `int` array and loop thought that array for all cords.

```
int[] line1 = new int[]{x1,y1,x2,y2};
int[] line2 = new int[]{x3,y3,x4,y4};
```

If you wonder how to draw the head you can use `drawPolygon`

```
int[] head = new int[]{x,y};

final int headSize = 50; //width and height in px
g.drawPolygon(head[0], head[1], headSize, headSize);
```

Hope it helped.
Regards -Max

Comment: problem is with the Graphics class is that it literally erases everything else and the only thing left is the line. Using public void paint(Graphics g) 
 {
   g.drawLine(25, 0, 25, 50);
   g.setColor(Color.black); 
 }

Comment: I figured I will just use an actual picture.